# Can't get my array loop right

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting an `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

```
string[] paths = { 
                        "\\\\server\\c$\\folder\\subfolder\\user1\\300\\1\\abc.docx",
                        "\\\\server\\c$\\folder\\subfolder\\user2\\400\\1\\xyz.docx",
                    };

FileInfo[] f = new FileInfo[paths.Length];

for (int i = 0; i <= paths.Length; i++)
{
    f[i] = new FileInfo(paths[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(f[i].Length);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why, any ideas?

Comment: use `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Also, if you don't need the index `i`, you can actually use `foreach` instead of `for` to avoid such error. Consider also of using `List` instead of `Array` for your `FileInfo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `<` instead of `<=`

```
for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
{
    f[i] = new FileInfo(paths[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(f[i].Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays start counting itens from 0. So, if you have an array with length 2, your objects will be in position [0] and [1]. If you try to access the position [2], you'll get the *Index was outside the bounds of the array* exception, because index 2 doesn't exist in this array.

In your for loop, you're using *<= paths.Length*. Your paths length is 2. 2 is less or equals 2, so your code will be executed like this

```
f[2] = new FileInfo(paths[2]) //Position 2 doesn't exist
```

To solve this, just change from:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= paths.Length; i++)
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two items in your array

```
paths[0], paths[1]
```

Your looping over three items

```
paths[0], paths[1], paths[2]
```

To correct this, change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= paths.Length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
```